# Capture gestures anywhere in Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, gestures

Basic idea is to provide Windows 8 with extra gestures, something like hotkey but for gestures. I do understand, it cannot be done for a "Windows 8 Store" applications, but it might be still be possible for a WPF or Windows Forms application. It would be even better if I was proven wrong on this, so that the App could run even on Windows 8 RT tablets.

Anybody has any ideas on how this could be done?

I would prefer to do it in C#, but can do C++ if i really have to.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 support only default gestures:
[image]

But You can write your own gestures like "Touch and Hold by 10 sec".

What gestures do You need?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I need guidens on how to write a cutom interceptor for touch in Windows 8. A hook that is in thebackground and listens to the touch ggestures, and if the hook has a matching gesture in its internal dictionary, it executes the associated action. Else passes the gesture to the next hook in the queue.